# Rectangles instead of text

Tags: 11.04, fonts, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fonts totally unreadable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27305/fonts-totally-unreadable)

I have this problem:
I see rectangles in the places where should be text. This happens, for example in `Code::Blocks` in the build log tab, in the warning lines, the rest of the text is OK.
This also happens in certain message boxes of Ubuntu. And in the subtitles text in the default video player, some lines, not all.

Here is an image of the rects:

[image]

Comment: What locale do you use? If it is something unique like Japanese or something, you may be missing fonts or language support packages.

Comment: @Rinzwind I didn't try to remove it, I was trying to make it link to the full sized image. It worked in the preview at least...

Comment: I have a similar problem when i move code from a mac to a linux! have you done that? :)

Comment: Do you have the same problems if you use english as language? :)

Comment: I use the english-usa locale. I didn't move code from a mac to a linux.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file? The default on ubuntu is UTF8 if the files are encoded in a different encoding that is not recognised the unrecognised characters are replaced with blocks.

Comment: This is not a file, this is a program. It uses UTF8, and that is the encoding of my Ubuntu. This not only happens in that program, but also in the subtitles on totem movie player, and in some message boxes of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved!
I reinstalled the Ubuntu fonts with this command:
`apt-get install --reinstall ttf-ubuntu-font-family`

Then I rebuilt the font information files with this command:
`fc-cache -f -v`

And Solved the problem! :)
I found the solution in another question:
[Fonts totally unreadable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27305/fonts-totally-unreadable/58214#58214)