# Unreadable rectangular font

Tags: graphics, display, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

> **Followed from previous post:**
>   [Rectangles instead of text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57967/rectangles-instead-of-text)

I am using ubuntu 16.10.After installation of ubuntu these rectangular boxes appeared in the homepage of google, where in place of the languages "Telegu" and "Kannad" these boxes appeared, and also in certain file names(as shown).So as a fix I installed the respective language packs and the google homepage problem got fixed.And for the filename problem I followed the solution given above   but it didn't work.Here is the screenshot

[image: screenshot]
How to fix this?

Comment: You are missing the font. Installing appropriate font should fix the problem.

Comment: Can you please specify which one I am missing, as I have already tried reinstalling ubuntu fonts.

Comment: Well, "invalid encoding" indicates that the name of the file is encoded in something else but UTF-8. Hence an encoding problem rather than a font problem.