# rectangles instead of fonts in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts

Ubuntu lost all fonts:

[image: screenshot]

I was adding a new font on Ubuntu following the [instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/manually-install-fonts-ubuntu-16-04/) by typing:

```
sudo chown root:staff /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ -R
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/* -R
sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
```

After that I typed:

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

And all my fonts disappeared (see the screenshot).

I found some topics on forums like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27305/fonts-totally-unreadable/58214#58214), but nothing helped.

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you try to remove the new font and rebuild the cache again?

Comment: Thanks for giving an idea! I blindly entered to the '/usr/local/share/fonts/' and found that this folder is empty. So I downloaded Ubuntu fonts manually from the [official website](http://font.ubuntu.com/), and opened each of the of them in Font viewer and clicked blindly to the button install on upper right corner. After I did that and relaunched **gnome** all the fonts came back! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a few unsuccessful attempts I found the solution for my problem:

1. Manually download Ubuntu fonts from the [official website](http://font.ubuntu.com/),
2. Unpack it and open each in Font Viewer (that in my case was automatically by just clicking on each of the file).
3. On the [right corner click INSTALL](http://www.howtogeek.com/192980/how-to-install-remove-and-manage-fonts-on-windows-mac-and-linux/) (do it for all the fonts).
4. At this point you start to see some fonts.
5. In my case the problem was with some wrong lines that I put before all that started. So I wrote the next:

> sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
>
> sudo fc-cache -fv

After that everything returned  in the normal way.

Comment: Why didn't you simply install the `ttf-ubuntu-font-family` package?

Comment: I didn't know about this option, but in my case it seems like I changed something with the paths where fonts were located.

Comment: My theory is that you removed the `ubuntu-desktop` package (not recommended!) and that the Ubuntu fonts were removed via `sudo apt autoremove`.

Comment: I think it was not my case. I didn't touch 'ubuntu-desktop' and didn't use 'sudo apt autoremove'.

Comment: sudo fc-cache -fv found for me. and restart session